# How can I change the standard behavior of z3 functions?

Tags: z3, smt

I have a (get-model) query for Z3 which returns this function:

```
(define-fun rules ((x!0 Tree)) Bool
(ite (= x!0 (node "mann" (cons (node "adam" nil) nil))) true
(ite (= x!0 (node "mensch" (cons (node "adam" nil) nil))) true
true)))
```

When using this code:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Tree leaf (node (value String) (children TreeList)))
                       (TreeList nil (cons (car Tree) (cdr TreeList)))))
(declare-const list TreeList)
(declare-const fact1 Tree)
(declare-const fact2 Tree)

(assert (not (is-leaf fact1)))
(assert (not (is-leaf fact2)))
(assert (not (= list nil)))

(assert (= (value fact1) "mann"))
(assert (= (value fact2) "adam"))
(assert (= (children fact1) list))

(assert (= fact2 (car list)))


(declare-const list2 TreeList)
(declare-const fact3 Tree)
(declare-const fact4 Tree)

(assert (not (is-leaf fact3)))
(assert (not (is-leaf fact4)))
(assert (not (= list2 nil)))

(assert (= (value fact3) "mensch"))
(assert (= (value fact4) "adam"))
(assert (= (children fact3) list2))

(assert (= fact4 (car list2)))

(declare-fun rules (Tree) Bool)
(assert (= (rules fact1) true))
(assert (=> (rules fact1) (rules fact3)))


(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The problem is I need the function "rules" to return false, whenever the argument is not one of the trees I have asserted rules for it to be true, but I can't find a way to edit the last "else" in the function. (get-model) seems to always use the most common answer of the function as it's answer if none of the rules work and since I only have rules for trees which make the answer true it uses true for the else as well, but I can't use the function that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to model Prolog like "closed-world" assumption here. This is not how SMT solvers work: They will find a model that will satisfy all the requirements, and everything else is fair game. That is, if you want no other value to satisfy your `rules`, then you have to state that explicitly.

You might want to look at datalog modeling though, which seems closer to what you are trying to express: https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/fixedpoints

Comment: I read through that site already and I don't think there is anything that helps me there. And you are right, I need to simulate  Prolog in Z3 for my bachelor thesis. Iassumed there must be a rule I can use that makes the else of the function false, but everything I do just adds more special cases to rules

Comment: Actually I have to correct myself. I read through it again, and I think I can make it work with this. So thank you for saving my bachelor thesis